# Can't select Java EE version for new web application in netbeans 7.3.1

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans

[image]

I couldn't select the Java EE version and the next button is not working. Finally when I click the finish button, I'm taken to the next page where I couldn't select a framework and thus couldn't complete the process.

[image]

Comment: Do you install Java EE plugin?

Comment: yes.. installed and active

Comment: The Java versions available are also determined by the server of your choice. It's just a wild guess but this may be related to some server misconfiguration. Do you have Glassfish pre-installed with Netbeans? Can you select the Java version if you select Glassfish?

Comment: yes it's working fine with Glassfish server... Is there anyway to make it work with Tomcat???

Comment: @Alfa It usually does work with Tomcat. You have to make sure your configuration is alright. Go to `Tools>Servers`, select Apachy Tomcat from the list on the left hand side and go to the `Platform` tab. Do you have a Java platform associated with the server?

Comment: Yes, it's JDK 1.7(Default)..